# How to get trafficStats information from android by time?

Tags: android, network-traffic

Is there a way how to get trafficStats from some date? For example from last month.

I´m using this [Get wifi traffic stats android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677403/get-wifi-traffic-stats-android) and as u can see from the code there is only number value of traffic in this file, but for example in DroidStats app data are counted from last day/month etc.

Also value is always 0 when i reboot my phone or when i´m messing up with settings of network is there another file somewhere or do i have to store this data myself if i don´t want to lose them?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way how to get trafficStats from some date? For example from last month.

You would have had to have been running last month, collected the data yourself, and saved it to a database or something. `TrafficStats` does not have *any* history. It only reports current cumulative values, except for resets (e.g., reboots).

> Also value is always 0 when i reboot my phone

Correct. This is working as intended.

> do i have to store this data myself if i don´t want to lose them?

Yes.