# Measuring WiFi Packets Only in Android Nougat

Tags: java, android, wifi, traffic, packets

I'm trying to measure the number of packets being sent and received over WiFi only on Android Nougat. Unfortunately, it looks like they removed access to "/sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/*" in Nougat according to this discussion:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208172

Searching for ways to measure wifi packets always leads me back to this answer (or similar):

[Get wifi traffic stats android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677403/get-wifi-traffic-stats-android/29908967)

That is, to read "/sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/*" (rx_bytes, tx_bytes, etc)

When I try to read them, AndroidStudio shows that the app can't read those files because permission is denied.

I've looked into TrafficStats but it seems there isn't a way to separate WiFi stats from all network stats. Does anyone know of a way to measure WiFi packets only?

(For background, I'm trying to update the PowerTutor app to work with my Nexus 6p, which I've updated to Nougat. The source code I'm working off is found here: https://github.com/msg555/PowerTutor)

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, it seems the TrafficStats class works fine for my purposes.

Here's what I ended up doing, and it's working to get only WiFi data on a Nexus 6p with Android 7.0:

```
long transmitPackets = TrafficStats.getTotalTxPackets() - TrafficStats.getMobileTxPackets();
long receivePackets = TrafficStats.getTotalRxPackets() - TrafficStats.getMobileRxPackets();
long transmitBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
long receiveBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
```

I tested it by checking the output with WiFi on and off, and it shows no power consumption with WiFi off (like it is supposed to). Just for good measure, I streamed a youtube video with just WiFi enabled and once with just mobile data enabled to confirm that using TrafficStats is working properly.